# How to customize Qt Items' paint event?

Tags: qt, listview, qt5

I'd like to write a music player, and I want to implement a music info list like this:

| ID | liked | download | name | artists | album | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | a button here | a download button here | music name | ... | ... | 02:30 |

it can be implemented with QTableWidget or QTreeWidget, but when I want to re-rendering the whole item background as a progress bar when downloading music, I couldn't find a function like this:

```cpp
void QMusicListWidgetItem::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    int pos = this->downloadProgress / 1.0 * width();
    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 120, 248));
    painter.drawRect(0, 0, pos, height());
    painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0));
    painter.drawRect(pos, 0, width() - pos, height());

    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}

void QMusicListWidgetItem::updateProgressSlot(float progress) {
    this->downloadProgress = progress;
    update();
}
```

I tried to use delegate, but delegate's paint function can not re-render the whole item background. it can only customize the single cell's display effect.

What's the correct solution of this demind?

Comment: Rather than try to change the drawing of a QTableWidget, could you just make the cells transparent and draw your progress bar behind it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the item view is inherited from the scroll area, so how to make the progress bar and item respond to scroll events together? maybe multiple items will be downloading at the same time, I don't know how to insert the progress bar into the inherited scroll area.

Comment: You want the progress bar to scroll?

Comment: What I mean is that if there are too many items in the widget, qtablewidget will automatically display a vertical scroll bar, so if the progress bar is placed under the item, I need to find some way to let the user move the progress bar and the item together when scrolling.